# The result of command Helm get values don't include comments

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a values file `values-production.yaml` with comments such as:

```
# some other comments
# another comments
image: xxxx
```

And I use command `helm install -n=test --values=values-production.yaml some-chart` to deploy application on my Cluster. But, when I used command `helm get values test`, the result just like this:

```
image: xxx
```

There is no any comments. Where is my comments? How to keep comments?

My Helm version:
Client: v2.11.0
Server: v2.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible, as `helm install` doesn't upload your `values-production.yaml` file as is. Rather, it constructs an object representing all the values from various defaults and inputs, then converts that object into a file that it posts to the server. Any comments will be lost in the conversion to the object.

The core of how the `helm install` command is implemented is [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/df5ca23a418199c1b2af3abfc420f8339d0b9b8e/cmd/helm/install.go#L236-L356):

```golang
func (i *installCmd) run() error {
    // omitting some code
    // note below rawVals is the output of the vals function

    rawVals, err := vals(i.valueFiles, i.values, i.stringValues, i.fileValues, i.certFile, i.keyFile, i.caFile)

    // omitting some code
    // note below the client asks the server to install the chart, passing values
    // via rawVals constructed above

    res, err := i.client.InstallReleaseFromChart(
        chartRequested,
        i.namespace,
        helm.ValueOverrides(rawVals),
        helm.ReleaseName(i.name),
        helm.InstallDryRun(i.dryRun),
        helm.InstallReuseName(i.replace),
        helm.InstallDisableHooks(i.disableHooks),
        helm.InstallDisableCRDHook(i.disableCRDHook),
        helm.InstallSubNotes(i.subNotes),
        helm.InstallTimeout(i.timeout),
        helm.InstallWait(i.wait),
        helm.InstallDescription(i.description))

    // more code omitted
}
```

and [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/df5ca23a418199c1b2af3abfc420f8339d0b9b8e/cmd/helm/install.go#L387-L439) is what `vals` does -- notes that the data from the value files goes into the `base` object and that thing is what is finally serialized to YAML and returned by `vals`:

```golang
func vals(valueFiles valueFiles, values []string, stringValues []string, fileValues []string, CertFile, KeyFile, CAFile string) ([]byte, error) {
    base := map[string]interface{}{}

    // omitting code that populates base with all the values from valuesFiles, etc.

    return yaml.Marshal(base)
}
```

Helm isn't intended to be used for file-sharing, if there's text in `values-production.yaml` that you want to store, retrieve, and share that isn't semantically meaningful to Helm (like comments), you'll have to consider a different solution.  Not sure what your use-case is, but you could consider some blobstore service, DropBox, etc.

Comment: I'm using Cloud Provider/Platform called [Alibaba Cloud](https://www.alibabacloud.com/en)(maybe you heard that). I deploy an Application on that platform panel and using command `helm get values <release name>`  can get values content with comments on my localhost, the comments was written on platform panel.  That means Tiller stored comments?

Comment: Did you deploy the application in that case via `helm install` command, or through the GUI panel?

Comment: I deploy application through GUI panel called service-catalog, I can write values content with comments on GUI, then click deploy button and it will do. when I finish deploying, I execute `helm get values` on my localhost, the result is my content with comments written on GUI pannel. How do you think this is achieved?

Comment: Most likely, the Alibaba GUI is posting data to Helm in a manner that's different from how the Helm CLI implements the `install` command. The `helm get` command likely gets whatever data was posted, whatever text file that is (comments and all).  But `helm install` CLI and the Alibaba GUI are posting data that `helm get` is later getting in different ways probably.